# FTDI connection: FT4232HL

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, ftdi

I'm working on a PCB Design where is needed flashing EEPROM. At the beginning, I wanted to add FTDI FT4232HL on my design, but I have thought it after and maybe is better option to use a FTDI flasher than adding a FTDI IC on every PCB.

Is there any advantage on add ftdi chips directly on the design?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The FT4232HL chip doesn't contain internal EEPROM, see Figure 2.1 of the [datasheet](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT4232H.pdf). If your PCB design requires EEPROM and not USB to UART interface then I don't think this chip (or any other FTDI chip) will help you. Some FTDI chips do contain a small amount of EEPROM memory, but that is mostly for configuring the USB engine (i.e., the VID/PID and other options).

The only advantage to adding the FT4232HL that I can think of is where you need both EEPROM memory and USB-to-UART interface, in which case the external EEPROM could be shared between the FT4232HL and your other need (microcontroller).

To keep the FTDI chip off-board, just add this circuit below. The 90120-0766 connector will mate directly with most 6-pin FTDI cables. The reason for R39 is so you can use the +5V supply from the FTDI cable for convenience by tapping onto the resistor lead.

[image]

Comment: Two of the chip 4 channels can be configured as SPI or I2C, which means they _can_ be used to interface user's EEPROM chip (not the one used to store USB configuration). Rather cumbersome design, but certainly doable.

Comment: I agree, that configuration is a good option for this chip. Unfortunately it is unclear if the question at hand is to use the FTDI chip only for access to the EEPROM or why the EEPROM is needed in the first place. If we had more insight to the design then we could offer better opinions of the advantages and disadvantages that were requested.

Comment: The FTDI chip target is only flash EEPROM needed for some ICs boards. I have seen this configuration in some evaluation board design, but if i build several boards, I think I can save money and time deleting this component and use an external FTDI device USB to UARTto flash eeproms (something like this: https://www.tme.eu/es/details/ft4232hq-module/modulos-usb/ftdi/ft4232h-mini-module/?brutto=1&currency=EUR&gclid=CjwKCAiAp8iMBhAqEiwAJb94z86Ki1JY0z2cpfoeky_2ff6NHa8ZkKcKo5BzuuTm8E5Vamudr437rxoCRWsQAvD_BwE)

Comment: Juanma, I agree it is easier and less expensive to just keep the chip off-board. I edited my answer to show how we add the FTDI cable support to our PCB projects.